# What is the equivalant of the following Ninject statement in Structuremap

Tags: ninject.web.mvc, structuremap3

What is the equivalent of the following in Structuremap

```
kernel.Bind<IQueryDispatcher>().To<QueryDispatcher>();
kernel.Bind<ICommandDispatcher>().To<CommandDispatcher>();

kernel.Bind(x => x
  .FromAssembliesMatching("MyApp.dll")
  .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
  .BindAllInterfaces());

kernel.Bind(x => x
  .FromAssembliesMatching("MyApp.dll")
  .SelectAllClasses().InheritedFrom(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
  .BindAllInterfaces());
```

-Arun

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
public class MyAppRegistry : Registry
{
    public MyAppRegistry()
    {
        this.For<IQueryDispatcher>().Use<QueryDispatcher>();
        this.For<ICommandDispatcher>().Use<CommandDispatcher>();
        Scan(scan =>
        {
            scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(a => a.FullName.StartsWith("MyApp"));
            scan.WithDefaultConventions();
            scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>));
            scan.AddAllTypesOf(typeof(ICommandHandler<>));
        });
    }
}
```